# Implementing sessionStorage in between page hops

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two codes, one is form.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="D:\frameworks\jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#sub").on("click", function(){
                sessionStorage.n1 = $("#no1").val();
                sessionStorage.n2 = $("#no2").val();
                location.href = "main.html";
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    No1:<input type="text" id="no1">
    No2:<input type="text" id="no2">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="sub"> 
</body>
</html>
```

and the other is main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="D:\frameworks\jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Main</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var n1_arr = new Array();
        var n2_arr = new Array();
        $(function(){
            n1_arr.push(sessionStorage.getItem("n1"));
            n2_arr.push(sessionStorage.getItem("n2"));
            $("#a").click(function(){
                location.href = "form.html";
            });
            $("#s").click(function(){
                for(var i = 0; i < n1_arr.length; i++)
                {
                    alert(n1_arr[i] + " and " + n2_arr[i]);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Add" id="a">
<input type="button" value="Show" id="s">
</body>
</html>
```

I want these to work like this:
First, main.html will open, and on clicking on the 'Add' button, the form.html will open in the same browser tab. The user will enter two numbers in the text boxes with id's no1 and no2. The user will then click on 'Submit' and then again, main.html should open(again in the same browser tab). The user will continue to do this for as long as he wants. On clicking the 'Show' button, alerts of all the values entered by the user, separately in pairs, will occur. How can I achieve this? In this case, only the last entered pair is alerted.

Comment: You should use `setItem` to store in `sessionStorage` like `sessionStorage.setItem("n1",$("#no1").val());
sessionStorage.setItem("n2",$("#no2").val());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to run the command on console:
sessionStorage.clear();

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="D:\frameworks\jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Main</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var n1_arr = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("n1")) || [];
    var n2_arr = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("n2")) || [];
    $(function(){



        $("#a").click(function(){
            location.href = "form.html";
        });


        $("#s").click(function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < n1_arr.length; i++)
            {
                alert(n1_arr[i] + " and " + n2_arr[i]);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Add" id="a"> 
<input type="button" value="Show" id="s"> 
</body>
</html>
```

form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="D:\frameworks\jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $("#sub").on("click", function(){

            var n1 = sessionStorage.n1 || [];
            if(n1.length > 0){
                n1 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.n1);
            }
            n1.push($("#no1").val());
            sessionStorage.n1 = JSON.stringify(n1);

            var n2 = sessionStorage.n2 || [];
            if(n2.length > 0){
                n2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.n2);
            }

            n2.push($("#no2").val());
            sessionStorage.n2 = JSON.stringify(n2);

            location.href = "main.html";

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 No1:<input type="text" id="no1">
No2:<input type="text" id="no2">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="sub"> 
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted...Thanks

Comment: Your welcome, please don't forget the give a vote :) thaks

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you are overwriting your existing `n1` and `n2` values.

sessionStorage stores key value pairs, with the value being a string. When you do `sessionStorage.setItem('n1', 'test')` it will overwrite the existing value.

What you need to do is read the existing value (it will be a string), parse it, append your new value on the end, then insert the whole object back into storage. When storing an object it will be best to `stringify` it as JSON first.

If you need to store complex objects like arrays etc you may find it better to use indexedDB.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API